# Create external shortcut in shared drive by using Google drive api

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to create an external shortcut to some web on Google shared drive. There is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/third-party-shortcuts but I have no idea how to pass URL to the page I want.

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonSecret)
            .CreateScoped(Scopes)
            .CreateWithUser("myemail@company.com")
            .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

DriveService _driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
  HttpClientInitializer = credential,
  ApplicationName = "to-teamdrive"
});
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
  Name = "Test shortcut",
  MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk",
  Parents = new List<string> { "0AKSia6LzF-hvuk9PVA"}
};
var uploadRequest = _driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
uploadRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;
uploadRequest.Fields = "id";
var file = uploadRequest.Execute();
```

Additionally, executing this code throws:

> Message="The application associated with this shortcut file does not support shared drives."

I can create a "link" in my drive when skipping Parents property but even then I do not know how to add URL to this "link". It creates empty... file... on my drive.

Comment: shared drives is gsuite is the user you logged in as part of the gsuite domain?

Comment: I think so... I am an employee of the company and have the company email and access to Google services. I cannot however create shared drivers on my own. I can access them only. I can also create external shortcuts manually from the browser. However I log in with something like this: var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonSecret)
                .CreateScoped(Scopes)
                .CreateWithUser("mylogin@company.com")
                .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

Comment: I have tried to go to https://admin.google.com/ and it says that only GSuite accounts can access this URL and mine is a standard one.

Comment: exactly you need to use gsuite account to access that feture.

Comment: Strange, I can create shortcut by using my account from browser but through API I cannot? What is the point? Do you know where I can find this info?

Comment: uploadRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;  <--- becouse you have included support all drives.  That is not supported on a normal Gmail account.

Comment: We are using this to migrate files from one system to GDrive and it is working for me normally with this setting. Only shortcuts cannot be created in this way. it does not make sense. I can do everything with my account BUT not create shortcuts with API even though I can manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like those external links were not something I was looking for. To solve my problem it is enough to create a file with name: 'name.url', mimeType 'text/x-url' and content similar to this:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=<URL here>
```

I have no idea if this is common or works only for my organization (we have some modifications done to the google apps).